# Why does 耷濕 mean "simple, crude, shabby"?

Tags: cantonese

[耷濕 means shabby; simple and crude. "This term is used in Cantonese, not Mandarin/Standard written Chinese."](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/46298/) [Wiktionary says the same thing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%80%B7%E6%BF%95#Chinese).

But [耷](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%80%B7) means "big ear" (noun) or "droop" (verb). [濕](https://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%BF%95) means "damp". Neither means "simple, crude, shabby". Then where does this meaning stem from?

Googling "wet droop" showed me [this picture of "drooping wet tree leaves on a rainy morning"](https://www.dreamstime.com/wet-tree-leaves-morning-rain-closeup-drooping-rainy-stormy-spring-weather-making-everything-feel-damp-cool-image148516130). Is this germane?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The long version is 頭耷耷，眼濕濕。

"drooping head, wet eyes" means that you are in a low mood.